Device Fingerprinting
I'm looking to integrate a device fingerprinting mechanism into a framework where users can commit to a unique device fingerprint and later use it to prove their identity.
While I understand that many companies use device fingerprinting for fraud prevention and various security measures, most descriptions I come across are quite high-level and abstract. I'm specifically interested in the technical details: how the device fingerprint is generated, what specific attributes are used, how it's stored securely, and how it's later verified during the authentication process.
Can anyone provide detailed explanations or point me toward resources that delve into the technical aspects of device fingerprinting, including best practices and potential challenges?

There are too many possible devices and setups to consider. Specify details/capabilities of the devices, how much control users and the verification service have over the devices, and how much communication is expected/allowed.

@aiootp let's say the user is using an iPhone, and they want to generate a device fingerprint and commit to it using a Pedersen commitment. The user provides this commitment to a service. Later on the user wants to prove to the user that this is really them (for example they want to recover their key), so they provide the device fingerprint commitment again and prove that they are who they claim to be. How can this technically possible in regards to the process of generating a unique device finger using factors that are less likely to evolve or change with time

did my response answer your question? consider accepting it


I'm looking to integrate a device fingerprinting mechanism into a framework where users can commit to a unique device fingerprint and later use it to prove their identity.
[...]
Can anyone provide detailed explanations or point me toward resources that delve into the technical aspects of device fingerprinting, including best practices and potential challenges?

As this fingerprinting guide demonstrates in detail, fingerprinting is premised on the extensive use of uniquely identifiable metadata to correlate known users with active sessions. However, because data is a profitable resource, it can be challenging to distinguish services which dishonestly justify excessive data collection with security requirements. If possible, honest services should prefer the kinds of tools which meet their security requirements without nullifying the privacy of their users or violating the principle of consent. In fact, it is possible to use cryptographic protocols to authenticate based on metadata, both shared and secret, and which users can consent to incorporating during registration. There are existing attempts of at least some of these goals, eg. the WebAuthN standard, FIDO2 and Passkeys. I'll give other ideas for how this can be done.
Let user $\mathcal{U}$'s device hold a fingerprint key $U = g^{(u+k_u)}$, and the verification service $\mathcal{V}$ have identity key $V = g^{(v+k_v)}$. The $u$ and $v$ are private keys, while $k_u$ and $k_v$ are suitably long hashes of their private keys with private metadata and connection context. This combination creates unique keys for each user-service pair [0, 1], and can prevent unconsensual tracking and fingerprinting by other parties. It would be worthwhile to do something similar on elliptic curves or quantum-safe algorithms instead, or perhaps with attribute-based encryption (ABE), but I digress.
As shorthand, let's also assign all non-secret (pre-shared and/or real-time correlatable) "labels" [2, 3, 4] (1st party user ID, session ID/token, service name, service public key, user public key, round # of the protocol, protocol name, purpose, etc) respectively to each $\{\ell_U, \ \ell_V\}$. We'll also assign $\{\ell_u, \ \ell_v\}$ as all of their combined non-secret shared and secret non-shared labels (3rd party user IDs, hardware serial codes, PII, etc), respectively, and with canonical separation between non-secret and secret values. One set of goals for these labels is to enforce that authentication only succeed if the parties agree on the shared labels which are used, ensuring the same non-shared labels are used, and enabling real-time checking of device metadata specified in a consensual security policy without needing to store the metadata in a database.
With this information, a protocol similar to Triple Diffie-Hellman (3DH) can be used as a challenge and response tool to authenticate the unique fingerprint key and the device, without needing to share the private metadata, which is more common [5, 6, 7, 8] (and which is often promoted under "anonymous" data collection). Using such a forward-secure (FS) protocol could also mitigate pass-the-hash (PtH) type attacks, which are more possible when using a static authentication code or commitment to check against.

Warning: Here's a simplified toy example. There are many, sometimes subtle, challenges with doing secure authentication. Based on the question, mutual authentication doesn't seem to be a requirement. However, it's important to authenticate the service's keys and ensure the freshness of its messages. Specifically, to protect against key compromise impersonation (KCI), prevent replay attacks, PtH by a machine in the middle (MitM) forwarding messages (only partially addressed, due to metadata spoofing, with even proper run-time device metadata measurement and their incorporation as shared labels), or create a secure channel [9, 10, 11, 12]:



Authenticate User Device:



$\underline{\mathcal{V}:} \\
x \leftarrow \texttt{gen_key}(g,\ p) \\
k_v \leftarrow H\left(\ell_{vU},\ v\right) \\
k_x \leftarrow H\left(k_v,\ \ell_{vU},\ x\right) \\
X \leftarrow g^{(x+k_x)} \\
t \leftarrow \texttt{current_minute}() \\
\tau_V \leftarrow H_\text{MAC}(U^{(v+k_v)},\ U^{(x+k_x)}, \\
\hspace{5.8em}\ell_{VU},\ X,\ t) \\\\$
$\xrightarrow{\hspace{5em} X,\ \ \tau_V \hspace{5em}} \mathcal{U}
\\\\$
$\hspace{2em}\underline{:\mathcal{U}} \\
\hspace{2em}t \leftarrow \texttt{current_minute}() \\
\hspace{2em}\textbf{if }X \not\in \{2,\ \ldots,\ p-1\}\textbf{:} \\
\hspace{4em}\textbf{return } \ \bot \\
\hspace{2em}\textbf{if }\tau_V \neq H_\text{MAC}(V^{(u+k_u)},\ X^{(u+k_u)}, \\
\hspace{8.5em}\ell_{VU},\ X,\ t)\textbf{:} \\
\hspace{4em}\textbf{return } \ \bot \\
\hspace{2em}y \leftarrow \texttt{gen_key}(g,\ p) \\
\hspace{2em}k_u \leftarrow H\left(\ell_{uV},\ u\right) \\
\hspace{2em}k_y \leftarrow H\left(k_u,\ \ell_{uV},\ y\right) \\
\hspace{2em}Y \leftarrow g^{(y+k_y)} \\
\hspace{2em}\tau_U \leftarrow H_\text{MAC}(V^{(u+k_u)},\ X^{(u+k_u)}, \\
\hspace{7.6em}V^{(y+k_y)},\ X^{(y+k_y)},\ \\
\hspace{7.6em}\ell_{UV},\ X,\ Y,\ t,\ \tau_V) \\
\\\\$
$\mathcal{V}\xleftarrow{\hspace{5em} Y,\ \tau_U \hspace{5em}}
\\\\$
$\underline{\mathcal{V}:} \\
\textbf{if }Y \not\in \{2,\ \ldots,\ p-1\}\textbf{:} \\
\hspace{2em}\textbf{return } \ \bot \\
\textbf{if }\tau_U \neq H_\text{MAC}(U^{(v+k_v)},\ U^{(x+k_x)}, \\
\hspace{6.2em}Y^{(v+k_v)},\ Y^{(x+k_x)}, \\
\hspace{6.2em}\ell_{UV},\ X,\ Y,\ t,\ \tau_V)\textbf{:} \\
\hspace{2em}\textbf{return } \ \bot \\
\tau_{VU} \leftarrow H_\text{MAC}(U^{(v+k_v)},\ U^{(x+k_x)}, \\
\hspace{5.8em}Y^{(v+k_v)},\ Y^{(x+k_x)}, \\
\hspace{5.8em}\ell_{VU},\ X,\ Y,\ t, \\
\hspace{5.8em}\tau_V,\ \tau_U) \\
\textbf{return } \ \text{true} \\
\\\\$
$\xrightarrow{\hspace{5.5em} \tau_{VU} \hspace{5.5em}} \mathcal{U}
\\\\$
$\hspace{2em}\underline{:\mathcal{U}} \\
\hspace{2em}\textbf{if }\tau_{VU} \neq H_\text{MAC}(V^{(u+k_u)},\ X^{(u+k_u)}, \\
\hspace{8.5em}V^{(y+k_y)},\ X^{(y+k_y)}, \\
\hspace{8.5em}\ell_{VU},\ X,\ Y,\ t, \\
\hspace{8.5em}\tau_V,\ \tau_U)\textbf{:} \\
\hspace{4em}\textbf{return } \ \bot \\
\hspace{2em}\textbf{return } \ \text{true} \\
\\\\$
